# Java: How do I have a background drawn in a game under the double buffer?

Tags: java, performance, graphics, background

I have a game in java and have all my objects drawn on a double buffer and wanted to draw a background but don't want the background redrawn every frame, how do I only draw it once?

Comment: Draw the background and then draw the buffer on top of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the background on a `BufferedImage`, so that you don't have to recreate the background every frame.  However, you have to draw the background every frame.  This is standard Java animation.

Comment: Thanks, I had a simple application that was running very slow, thought it was because the background was being redrawn. However, I realized I was reloading the image files every frame.